# When trying to convert column data type NVARCHAR to INT getting error

Tags: sql

When trying to convert column data type NAVCHAR to INT receiving error. Simple code below:

```
SELECT [phone], FORMAT(CAST(PHONE AS int),'(000)-000-0000)')
FROM Sales.Customers
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 355
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '030-3456789' to data type int.

Comment: now that's the answer to your question, you cannot convert that to int because of the dash ('-')

Comment: So there is no way to format phone number to (000)-000-0000?

Comment: there is, just a different logic, wait i'll try to solve it myself, i'm just on the phone.. the best way is to replace that - with empty string, then use your query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query should be something like this:

```
SELECT [phone], FORMAT(CAST(REPLACE([phone],'-','')AS INT), '(000)-000-0000)')
FROM Sales.Customers
```

So if there's an invalid character to be converted to in (for this scenario dash is the one to be replaced), it will replace it with blank then format it with the format you want.

ex: '030-3456789'
 this will become (030)-345-6789

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: mark as answer if that's the solution to your problem,

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have rows with phone numbers stored as strings, which can't be converted to an int. To find out which, execute:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Sales.Customers
WHERE  ISNUMERIC(phone) = 0;
```

HTH

Comment: They are all stored as strings, is there are way to format string to way I want to represent phone as (000)-000-0000?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `TRY_CAST()`:

```
SELECT [phone],
       FORMAT(TRY_CAST(PHONE AS int), '(000)-000-0000)')
FROM Sales.Customers;
```

This returns `NULL` if the value cannot be converted -- which is better than getting an error.